# Listening Application (winsock2) behavior towards Port scanning (Syn Scan)

Tags: tcp, server, behavior, winsock2, difference

Should a server application that listens on a port, able to detect and logs down any connection attempt done by Syn Scanning?

**Test Scenario**

I had written a windows program which i simply called it "simpleServer.exe".
This program is just a simulation of a very basic server application.
It listens on a port, and wait for incoming messages.
The listening Socket was defined to be a TCP Stream Socket.
that's all that this program is doing.

I had been deploying this exact same program on 2 different machines, both running on windows 7 professional 64bit.
This machine will act as a host.
and they are stationed in the same network area.

then, using the program "nmap",
i used another machine on the same network, to act as a client.
using the "-sS" parameter on "nmap", i do a Syn Scan, to the IP and Port of the listening simpleServer on both machine (one attempt at a time).

(note that the 2 hosts already had "wireshark" started, and is monitoring on tcp packets from the client's IP and to the listening port.)

In the "wireshark" entry, on both machine, i saw the expected tcp packet for Syn Scan:

```
client ----(SYN)----> host

client <--(SYN/ACK)-- host

client ----(RST)----> host
```

the above packet exchange suggests that the connection was not established.

But on the "simpleServer.exe", only one of it had "new incoming connection" printed in the logs, while the other instance was not alerted of any new incoming connection, hence no logs at all.

**Code Snippets**

```
// socket bind and listen was done above this loop 
while(TRUE)
{
    sClient=accept(sListen,(SOCKADDR*)&remoteAddr,&nAddrLen);
    if(sClient == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Failed accept()");
        continue;
    }
    dwSockOpt (sListen);
    printf ("recv a connection: %s\n", inet_ntoa(remoteAddr.sin_addr));

    closesocket(sClient);
}
```

side note:
yes, since it is just a simple program, the flow might be a little funny, such as no *break* in the *while* loop. so please don't mind this simple and flawed design.

**Further Investigation**

i had also put a *getsockopt()* in the "simpleServer" right after it went into listening state, to check the differences of both the listening socket's SOL_SOCKET option.

one notable difference i found between the two hosts, is the SO_MAX_MSG_SIZE.
the host that detects the incoming connection has a Hex value of 0x3FFFFFFF (1073741823), while the other one that has no logs is 0xFFFFFFFF (-1). not sure if this is related or not, but i just spammed whatever differences that i may found in my test environment. the other value of the SOL_SOCKET are more or less the same.

side note: i tested on some other machine, which covers another windows 7 professional, windows server 2008 r2, windows server 2003. i am not sure if it is coincidence or not, but machine that have SO_MAX_MSG_SIZE == -1, they all did not detect the connection of the Syn Scanning. but maybe it is just a coincidence. i have nothing to prove tho.

**Help That I Needed**

- why is the different behavior from the 2 same of the same application on a different machine with the same OS?
- what determines the value of the SO_MAX_MSG_SIZE? considering two same OS but having 2 different values.

Answer (score 0):

If a connection is never established, `accept()` will never return. That disposes of 90% of your question.

The only explanation for the 'new incoming connection' (or 'recv a connection' or whatever it is) message is that something else connected.

SO_MAX_MSG_SIZE has no meaning for a TCP socket, let alone a listening TCP socket. So whatever variation you experienced is meaningless.

Comment: Hi EJP, thanks for the reply. by the way, what else could have been connecting to it? if i follow my traces on wireshark correctly, there is only packet that comes from the client. And the traces only appear when i run the nmap on the on the client.

Comment: There must be a SYN-SYN/ACK-ACK sequence for `accept()` to return.

Comment: which is why i'm trying to find out what is happening on my machine. i see a SYN-SYN/ACK-RST (there were never SYN-SYN/ACK-ACK found in wireshark traces), but `accept()` somehow returns a value. and also printed the IP of the client. and it only happens on a certain machine (including my laptop). by the way, sorry if i might have used the incorrect term/sentences in my question.